# Search and aggregate in 6000 row csv/json document

Tags: json, database, csv, search

I'm looking for a good solution for full text search in a document with approx. 6000 rows, 6 columns in each.

I've currently tried Meteor and MongoDB, but I'm struggling a bit with high CPU when doing the aggregations, and the pub/sub response time is quite slow.

I need to search for multiple words, and sum/aggregate a number field.

What technologies is worth looking in to for a fast and easy setup?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor pub/sub is not suited for sending large datasets at once. It is rather designed for reactive updates  of data (automatically update on data-change).

In an optimal condition, this data is sent in small chunks to the client via lazy loading,  using a limit, and completed on demand.

**However**, Mongoldb itself is good for searching in large datasets! You may search on that topic.

The first results on googling "mongodb search in large data set" returned these articles:

https://www.mongodb.com/big-data-explained

http://johnpwood.net/2011/05/31/fast-queries-on-large-datasets-using-mongodb-and-summary-documents/

This might be a starting point.

Then you may try to stick with your search/aggregations on the server-side of meteor and return **only your results** to the client (using a lazy loading mechanism).

Regarding your CPU load, you may also consider the first article and workaround "greedy queries":

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/